# TFS/ Azure branching and Merging strategy

Tags: merge, tfs, branching-and-merging

I recently got assigned to a new team and this team use TFS(Azure) as version controlling tool. I noted that they don't have Master/Dev branching strategy. **Instead they create new branch from the latest branch and do the new Sprint work**. Now we have below situation. This will definitely cause **Headless merge** and **lot of merge conflicts with time consuming manual work**. I would like to know, are there any technique which I can use to minimize merge conflicts and manual work.
(I have worked with Bitbucket/Github and bit new to TFS)

[image]

As per the image there are changes in **Branch B** which is hold at the moment. Team will start working on **Branch C** which created from **Branch A** for another one month. Once development is completed **Branch C** will be deployed to Production. Then we need to get the changes of **Branch B** to **branch D** which created form **Branch C**. (Simply Branch D needs to have changes of Branch C and Branch B). While doing this there will be a Headless merge and lot of conflicts. Is there any strategy which I can follow before start working of Branch C to resolve this issue ?

Furthermore when should I introduce Master / Dev branching concept ?

Comment: Can you clarify which version control system you're using in TFS? TFS supports TFVC (MS certralised Version Control) and Git (Open Source distributed Version Control)

Comment: @JamesReed It's TFVC

Comment: So presumably, to merge B in to D without first merging back in to A you need to perform a baseless merge. That sounds painful and potentially dangerous. I don't think there is anything you can do to make this process better. TFVC really relies on branches having a parent / child relationship so the proper merge path would be B -> A -> D. I'm not sure if this would make the merges less painful, but you would be working with the tool rather than fighting against it.